# Looping through the rows of a dataframe to create a cumulative sum

Tags: r, for-loop, conditional-statements

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1)
start <- mdy("01/01/2022")
end <- start + as.difftime(99, units = "days")
days <- seq(from = start, to = end, by = 1)
days <- sample(days, 100, replace = T)
expiry <- seq(from = start, to = end + 300, by  = 1)
expiry <- sample(expiry, 100, replace = T)
x <- sample(1:10, 100, replace = T)
df <- tibble(days = days, expiry = expiry, value = x)
df <- df %>% filter(days != expiry) %>% arrange(days)
df$expiry[2] = mdy("01-02-2022") 
df
# A tibble: 100 × 3
   days       expiry     value
   <date>     <date>     <int>
 1 2022-01-01 2022-07-23    10
 2 2022-01-01 2022-01-02     3
 3 2022-01-02 2022-10-27     4
 4 2022-01-06 2022-12-22     2
 5 2022-01-07 2022-03-19     5
 6 2022-01-10 2023-01-08     2
 7 2022-01-13 2022-06-23     8
 8 2022-01-13 2022-05-02     5
 9 2022-01-14 2022-08-02     5
10 2022-01-14 2022-03-06     1
# ℹ 90 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

What I want to create is a dataframe which has for each date in the year the sum of all the value entries in the above dataframe which have days <= date and expiry >= date. I tried the below.

```
days <- seq(from = mdy("01/01/2022"), to = mdy("12-31-2022"), by = 1)
s <- rep(0, length(day))
i = 0

for (d in day){
  for (v in df){
    if (v[1] <= d & v[2] >= d){
      s[i] = s[i] + v[3]
    }
  }
  i <- i + 1
}
tb <- tibble(day, s)
# A tibble: 365 × 2
   day            s
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 2022-01-01     0
 2 2022-01-02     0
 3 2022-01-03     0
 4 2022-01-04     0
 5 2022-01-05     0
 6 2022-01-06     0
 7 2022-01-07     0
 8 2022-01-08     0
 9 2022-01-09     0
10 2022-01-10     0
# ℹ 355 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

The result here should be that the first 3 entries of s are 10+3=13, 10+3+4=17, 10+4=14. Since 2022-01-03 > 2022-01-02 the expiry of entry 2 from the table df.

Expected output based on the first 10 rows should look like this:

```
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   x              y
   <date>     <dbl>
 1 2022-01-01    13
 2 2022-01-02    17
 3 2022-01-03    14
 4 2022-01-04    14
 5 2022-01-05    14
 6 2022-01-06    16
 7 2022-01-07    21
 8 2022-01-08    21
 9 2022-01-09    21
10 2022-01-10    23
```

Essentially what Im trying to do is mimic the sumifs function in excel:

[image]

Comment: isnt the expiration always greater than date?. could you include a counter example row and how the sum should look like

Comment: @Onyambu Maybe I need to give more detail but no for example on 2022-01-3, the first 2 entries of the dataframe one has an expiration on 2022-01-02 and so it would not count towards the sum, however the other entries on row 1 and row 2 will because the expiry is greater then the date.

Comment: include it in the example and also include the expected output column

Comment: @Onyambu I updated the question, I can replicate what I am trying to do with the sumifs function in excel.

Comment: In your excel you have extra column E, in R you did not talk of that column

Comment: @Onyambu I think the confusion is how I named the columns in the second frame, I have the original dataframe of days, expiry and value. Which would correspond to A,B, C in the excel and then day, s correspond to E, F in tb. I was trying to iterate through the rows of df to fill the rows of s in tb.

Comment: @jpsmith Its SUMIFS(C:C, A:A, "<="&E1, B:B, ">="&E1) and then applied to every row in E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R we can do this with `dplyr` and the `join_by` function.

```
library(tidyverse)

days <- data.frame(x = days)

by <- join_by(x >= days, x <= expiry)

left_join(days, df, by) %>%
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarize(value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE))


# A tibble: 365 × 2
   x          value
   <date>     <int>
 1 2022-01-01    13
 2 2022-01-02    17
 3 2022-01-03    14
 4 2022-01-04    14
 5 2022-01-05    14
 6 2022-01-06    16
 7 2022-01-07    21
 8 2022-01-08    21
 9 2022-01-09    21
10 2022-01-10    23
```